# How to configure WordPress + plugins to support these commenting features

Tags: comments

Is it possible (and if so, how) to configure WordPress blog to support these feature for user comments? I want to use built-in comments, not 3rd party services like Disqus. If something cannot be achieved by configuring WordPress itself please suggest plugins that can achieve the following:

**1 + 2)** Every user that would like to leave a comment must be authenticated. Supported authentication methods must be Google, Twitter and Facebook auth, no other (e.g., it must be impossible to log in using generic OpenID provider or the built in WordPress authentication etc.)

**3)** If a visitor provides an email address, they can check a checkbox to be notified of new comments

**4)** Comments should be flat (not visually nested) but should allow references to other comments.

**5)** If there are too many comments, they should be loaded dynamically as user scrolls down (i.e., similarly how Twitter or Facebook work).

Can this be achieved using WordPress built-in comments plus some plugins?

Comment: I honestly think this question is far too localized. The purpose of WPSE isn't really "*research/Google for me the Plugins I need to do what I'm trying to do*".

Comment: I am new to WordPress and maybe someone who knows WordPress in and out with all the ecosystem around it will be able to help me and suggest useful configuration settings / plugins for this scenario.

Comment: This is a plain [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Sorry to say: Close voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1+2. what about the janrain engage plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/
3. subscribe to comments plugin mentioned by @chip bennet
4. chris pearson discusses flat, but referenced comments : http://www.pearsonified.com/2007/11/professional_stylish_comments_for_blogs.php
i'm not aware of any automated way to implement this, but i think it is a great idea
5. unsure

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible, either through using a plugin or adding this functionality right into a theme. Although I don't guarantee there is already a plugin that has this functionality available nor do I know of one, but I'm sure a simple Google search could bring up a lot of plugins that have potential.

Otherwise, you could always create it yourself if you have the PHP and WordPress knowledge to do so, or hire a freelancer to do it for you.

If you can dream it, you can build it with WordPress!

Comment: Obviously I'd rather just combine settings + plugins that are already available. I haven't used WP for a long time so I'm not sure what would be the best way to approach those 5 requirements or if they're possible to achieve at all.

Answer (score 0):

1) Authentication is available OOTB via Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion. You can require users to be logged in to comment.

2) Try something like the [Simple Facebook Connect Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/).

3) Try something like the [Subscribe To Comments Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/).

4) Nested comments are available OOTB via Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion.

5) I am unaware of any Plugins that allow for lazy load of comments; you may need to consult Google.

Comment: 1) Wordpress registration is not one of the 3 methods of authentication I mentioned. 2) FB plugin probably won't do Twitter and Google authentication, will it? Can I combine 3 such plugins? Other points: thanks, I'll look at it.

Comment: I'll amend the question so that points 1+2 are a single point (it's a bit confusing right now).